# PHP login form will not login a user with correct credentials

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, web, phpmyadmin

I have a php form that when the user submits with incorrect credentials gets appropriate error messages but when using correct credentials does not get login success message just the same incorrect credentials message. I have tried with both hashing password and without no luck. Here is my login function code:

```
function login($username, $password) {

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'jamaixan_bobsled';
$pass = 'v67fvg7gk_&g';
$db = 'db_for_site_67';
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$connected = mysql_select_db($db);

$user_id = user_id_from_username ($username);
$password = md5($password);

return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id_user`) FROM `table_of_users` WHERE 

`email_user` = `$username` AND `password_user` = `$password`") , 0) == 1) ? $user_id : `false`;
    }
```

Comment: Put an `if` statement after each `mysql` function to ensure it returns the value you are expecting. I can see four there where the return value has not been checked. Also, there is a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, so don't put it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use PDOs, a more secure way to handle DB request. mysql_* functions are deprecated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put username and password value in backticks, put them in quotes. You even placed `false` in backticks. Do like this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id_user`) FROM `table_of_users` WHERE 
            `email_user` = '$username'  AND `password_user` = '$password'");

return  (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) ? $user_id : false;
```

Comment: still no login success. I simply call this function in my index.php page so don't so it must still be an issue with the login function.?

Comment: look at the update plz

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_* or pdo... mysql is deprecated

```
function login($username, $password) 
{
    $cn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'jamaixan_bobsled', 'v67fvg7gk_&g', 'db_for_site_67') or die('Connection error!');

    $SQL = "SELECT COUNT(id_user) FROM table_of_users WHERE email_user = '%s' AND password_user = '%s'";

    $Query = sprintf($SQL, mysqli_real_escape_string($username), md5($password));

    $Result = mysqli_query($cn, $Query) or die( mysqli_error($cn) );

    $Rows = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);

    return ( isset($Rows[0]) && ($Rows[0] > 0) );
}
```

Comment: Yeah Im following a tutorial from a few years back that's why Im using MYSQL. However, tried your suggested method but still no success. Not sure where the problem lies as I simply call the login function in index.php page.

Answer (score -1):

```
function connectdb()
{
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbname='db_for_site_67';
    $dbuser="jamaixan_bobsled";
    $pwd="v67fvg7gk_&g";

    try
    {
        $db=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$pwd);
        if($db)
        {
            try
            {
                $dbselect=mysql_select_db($dbname,$db); 
                if(!$dbselect)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to select database: $dbname with error ". mysql_error());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to database with error ". mysql_error());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $db;
}


function login($username, $password) {

$user_id = user_id_from_username ($username);
$password = md5($password);
$conn1=connectdb();
$sql1="SELECT COUNT(`id_user`) FROM `table_of_users` WHERE `email_user` = $username AND `password_user` = $password";
$res1=mysql_query($sql1);
$res1=mysql_fetch_array($res1);
$res1=$res1['COUNT(`id_user`)'];
if($res1==1){
    echo "login sucessful";
} else {
    echo "login Failed";
}

    }
```

Comment: why `$username` and `$password` are in backticks ?

Comment: what is backticks ? i just separated the connection function that's all. i didn't get what you meant by that

Comment: oops..sorry ... missed that out ...will correct it ..thx

Comment: they must be in the quotes : ( quote = `'` )

Comment: The variable `$user_id` is defined but not used. Also, the query replicates the OP's SQL injection vulnerability - I take the view that these should not be copied verbatim without being fixed.